# SQL SELECT With Two Inner Functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    CompanyID, CompanyName, 
    dbo.GetCommaSeparatedOwnerNames(CompanyID), 
    GetCommaSeparatedOwnerEmails(CompanyID) 
FROM Companies
```

Obviously, every company has multiple owners.

`CommaSeparatedOwnerNames` and `GetCommaSeparatedOwnerEmails` functions look like the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetCommaSeparatedOwnerNames] (@CompanyID int)  
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @list VARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @list = COALESCE(@list+',' ,'') + OwnerName
    FROM Owners
    WHERE CompanyID = @CompanyID

    RETURN @list
END

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetCommaSeparatedOwnerEmails] (@CompanyID int)  
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @list VARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @list = COALESCE(@list+',' ,'') + OwnerEmail
    FROM Owners
    WHERE CompanyID = @CompanyID

    RETURN @list
END
```

Can I achieve the same query result without the waste of executing two similar functions?

I'm targeting SQL Server 2005 and above if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can USE STUFF and FOR XML to create the comma separated lists using correlated subqueries.

```
CREATE TABLE Companies (CompanyID INT, CompanyName VARCHAR(10))
CREATE TABLE Owners (CompanyID INT, OwnerName VARCHAR(10), OwnerEmail VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO Companies VALUES 
 (1,'BobCo')
,(2,'JoeCo')
INSERT INTO Owners VALUES 
 (1,'Bob_1','B1@Bob.com')
,(1,'Bob_2','B2@Bob.com')
,(2,'Joe_1','J1@Joe.com')
,(2,'Joe_2','J2@joe.com')

SELECT CompanyName 
      ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(OwnerName AS VARCHAR(MAX))
                FROM Owners o
               WHERE o.CompanyID=c.CompanyID
                 FOR XML PATH('')
              ), 1, 2, '') OwnerNames
      ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(OwnerEmail AS VARCHAR(MAX))
                FROM Owners o
               WHERE o.CompanyID=c.CompanyID
                 FOR XML PATH('')
              ), 1, 2, '') OwnerEmail
  FROM Companies c
```

And a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8041f/1).